# Как правильно написать цикл в The Descent на www.codingame.com?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    for i in range(8):
        mountain_h = int(input())  # represents the height of one mountain, from 9 to 0.

        for i in range(9) :        
 # Write an action using print            
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr)




              print("0")
              print("1")
              print("2")
              print("3")
              print("4")
              print("5")
              print("6")
              print("7")      
              #----------
              print("0")
              print("1")#Эти print надо вывести с циклом пропуская первые 
              print("2")#8print
              print("4")
              print("5")
              print("7")
              print("3")
              print("6")
     #-----------------------                    
              print("5")# Эти print надо вывести с циклом, но пропуская 
              print("2")#предыдущие 16 print и тд. до черты-------
              print("1")
              print("3")
              print("2")
              print("3")
              print("6")
              print("1")
              print("1")    
              print("1")   
     #-----------------------

              print("5")# и тд.до последнего варианта print
              print("1") #------такой чертой отвечен каждый вариант вывода
              print("7")# итого должно получиться 5 вариантов
              print("5")#более подробно можно посмотреть
              print("3")#задачу на www.codingame.com
              print("1")# 2 puzzle называется The Descent
              print("3")
              print("1")
     #------------------------------

              print("3")
```

Comment: Вопрос не очень понятен. А замысел в коде отличается от того, что в задачи.
Вам нужно запоминать самое большое значение mountain_h и его индекс i. И после получения всех высот гор, вывести индекс самой высокой горы.

Спасибо, за сайт -- очень прикольный ))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ- подумаю. Если решите этот пазл на сайте буду благодарна, если сюда разместите ваше решение.

Comment: Да я то могу выложить решение, но будет ли польза вам, если получите решение? :)

Comment: Да, новичек. Буду очень благодарна.Посмотрю-поучусь. Я потратила уже часов 5 . И пока больше не хочется. Кстати было бы интересно, как вывести эти принты один за другим. Пропуская уже отработавшие. Да это тупо, но все по отдельности проходит- проверяла. Буду благодарна. Можно в закрытом режиме или на почту.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заведите две переменных – максимальная высота горы `max_height = 0` и индекс горы c максимальной высотой `index = -1`, в цикле `for i in range(8):` сравниваете `max_height` и `mountain_h`, и если `mountain_h` больше или равен `max_height`, в `max_height` записываете `mountain_h`, а в `index` значение индекса горы `i`.

После окончания цикла выводите в консоль `index`.